# if ListBox Contains, don't add

Tags: c#, listbox

I've got a Method:

```
FillListBox();
```

I call this method from different places.. But sometimes it happens, that things were loaded twice!

Now I'm trying to do something like:

```
if (listBox.Items[1].ToString() == "hello")
{
   DO NOT FILL
}
else
{
   FILL
}
```

THIS DONT WORKS! :(

```
Fault: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index
```

And something like that:

```
if(listBox.Items.Contains("hello"))
{
   DONT FILL
}
```

Dont works too :(

What can I do?

Comment: Could you specify what's 'different places'? Can it be multithreaded?

Comment: Is this web, windows, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.. I just used myListBox.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
if(ListBox.NoMatches != listBox.FindStringExact("StringToFind"))
  {
      listBox.Items.Add("StringToAdd");
  }
```

or simply try this

```
 bool found = false;

 foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
 {
     if(item.ToString().Equals("StringToAdd"))
     {
         found = true;
         break;
     }
 }
if(!found)
    listBox.Items.Add("StringToAdd");
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I solved the problem..

I just used 

    myListBox.Items.Clear();

Comment: if think there been a small mistake, instead of !=, you should use == to perform this task

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if ( listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(x => x.Text == "hello"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
var item = listBox.Items.FindByValue("hello") // or FindByText
if (item != null)
{
   DONT FILL
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FindByValue' and no extension method 'FindByValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thats because `FindByValue` is on the webforms listbox, not the winforms one.

Comment: I solved the problem..

I just used 

    myListBox.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

You should try something along the lines of

```
foreach(ListItem item in listBox)
{ 
    if(item.Value == "YourFilter")
    { 
       DONT FILL 
    }
}
```

if your project is ASP

you should do

```
foreach(object item in listBox)
{ 
    if(item == "YourFilter")
    { 
       DONT FILL 
    }
}
```

if it's WPF, not sure which ListBox you're talking about.
Obviously this isn't the most elegant solution, but I suppose it's appropriate if you're just starting to learn C#.

Comment: I solved the problem..

I just used 

    myListBox.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

```
String newValue = "hello";
if (listBox1.Items.Cast<Object>().Any(x => x.ToString() == newValue))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: I just want to say thank you so much for this answer.  It's 7 years old and it's just fixed an issue that's been bugging me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

`listBox.Items.Contains("hello")` should work fine.

Comment: it works 4 me 2.. But in my case, how I'm using it, it don't works

Comment: I solved the problem..

I just used 

    myListBox.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

```
  var findByValue = ListBox2.Items.FindByValue(rdr.GetString(0));
                        if (findByValue == null)
                        {
                            ListBox2.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck