# ListBox.Items.Contains is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `ListBox.Items.Contains` to check for duplicates but it does not seem to be working. It's two strings that I'm comparing. I have looked at the values when debugging and they appear to be exactly the same, so it should show me a messagebox to say a duplicate was found.

The item gets added to the `myListBox` every time, even if there is a duplicate, up to a maximum of 6 items.

Note that I am using a vendor SDK and therefore have had to change some of the code a bit but it is functionally identical. Code below. I have commented on any custom controls to explain what they are.

```
//Custom control - is not inherited from ListBox but it does contain a listbox. It implements IBasicEnquiryControl2 which has a property Control which will be the .Net ListBox.
Class.Namespace.Windows.eListBox lstdisplay = (Class.Namespace.Windows.eListBox)EnquiryForm.GetControl("ListBox1",EnquiryControlMissing.Exception);
ListBox myListBox = (ListBox)lstdisplay.Control; 

//Returns an object from a custom class. ID property is used a bit further down, which is an int64 value
Class.Namespace.CR _cr = new Class.Namespace.CR.GetCR; 

//Value key pair object item. 
EnquiryListItem item; 
item = new EnquiryListItem(_cr.ID,ComboBox1.SelectedText); 

//Logic to check for duplicates.
if(myListBox.Items.Count < 6) {

    if (!myListBox.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())) {
        myListBox.BeginUpdate();                            
        myListBox.Items.Add(item);
        myListBox.EndUpdate(); 
    } 
    else { 
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Duplicate found", "Duped", MessageBoxButtons.OK); 
    }

}
```

Edit: The other question did not help as it doesn't seem to apply to my situation. It appears I cannot use Linq with this control, nor can I use the for loop suggested. I get errors such as `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox does not contain a definition for 'Add'` or the same but with `Any` as the missing definition. `System.Linq` is referenced.

Comment: Are the duplicates, trimmed IE could you be looking at spaces, tabs etc?

Comment: I believe you may be tripping over the "strings are actually pointers" reality, Does this [SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288367/how-to-check-if-an-item-is-already-in-a-listbox) or this [SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077741/if-listbox-contains-dont-add) help?

Comment: lol good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an item is already in a ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288367/how-to-check-if-an-item-is-already-in-a-listbox)

Comment: I will try checking for items rather than strings later on and report back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are adding `EnquiryListItem` to your `Listbox.Items`, not strings. When you ask your ListBox if it contains a string it uses the default equality comparer for `EnquiryListItem`. It will always be "No" because `enquiryListItem.Equals(someString)` will never be true.

You will probably need to iterate over the items collection and find a duplicate yourself. This is relatively easy with Linq

```
myListBox.Items.Cast<EnquiryListItem>().Any(item=> item.Text == ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())
```

Comment: My control has no definition for `Any` apparently. I have run into issues with using Linq in this application before, even when including System.Linq. I'll see if I can cast the control to the correct type.

Comment: It looks like the Items property is an IEnumerable, but Linq only works with IEnumerable<T>. It looks like you can convert to an IEnumerable<T> with Cast<T> or OfType<T>. I have updated my answer. Still remember to add "using System.Linq;"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare them using `contains` since that's used to compare the objects themselves. You will need to compare the string values directly.

You can change

```
if (!myListBox.Items.Contains(ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())) {
```

to

```
if (!myListBox.Items.Cast<String>().Any(item => item == ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())){
```

To compare the string values

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection does not contain a definition for 'Cast'` when attempting this solution

Comment: @SyntaxError the `.Cast<T>` is part of Linq. Please add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @dbvega I know, but the SDK I am using does not support that library (it's C# version 4.0 and has some weird nuances). This was over a year ago, I think I figured something out in the end.