# ListBox duplicate check

Tags: c#, listbox

I did post [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099868/listbox-items-contains-is-not-working) yesterday but I haven't had any further responses because there were two answers posted. Unfortunately none of them will work for me. Apologies if this is against the rules to repost a similar question.

I am trying to check a `ListBox` for duplicates when pressing a button. It should be adding the value of what's a `ComboBox` to the `ListBox`.

All the answers suggested using `Linq` queries, like this

```
myListBox.Items.Any(item=>((EnquiryListItem)item).Text == ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())
```

or this

```
if (!myListBox.Items.Cast<String>().Any(item => item == ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())){
```

However, my control doesn't have an entry for `Any` or `Cast`.

I tried using a `foreach` loop like the one below, but I get an error, `object does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`.

```
            foreach (var item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
               if (item.Text.Contains(Combobox1.SelectedText.ToString()))
               {
                   //select item in the ListBox
                   debugMsg("Duplicate","");
                   break;
               } else {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Combobox1.SelectedItem); }
            }
```

Is there any other method I can use? I've searched both SO and the internet in general but come across the same suggestions each time - almost always using Linq, which apparently won't work for my vendor specific SDK windows form application. They have documented their `ListBox` control and suggest that it inherits the .NET control but only supply code to add/remove items, with no duplicate checking.

Comment: First off item.text isn't a thing. use item.ToString() second i'd use selectedItem.ToString on the combobox

Comment: Oh and the cast should work on a listbox item make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I've already got ` using System.Linq;` but none of the methods seem to be available to my control. In my question I did mention this. I have tried `item.ToString()` but nothing happens when I press the button (item is not added, messagebox doesn't display)

Comment: Are you sure you are using winforms? the provided answers on your last question work fine if i make a new project

Comment: Also use `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` selected text does not what you think it does

Comment: Well, it's a .NET application where I'm using an SDK. As far as I can tell it's based on winforms. The problem comes from some of the controls being custom, so I find that casts don't always work and Linq is often not supported. https://i.imgur.com/72dyLDA.png

Comment: If the controls are custom you might as well remove the winforms tag. All solutions you will get is people trying code on a regular listbox

Comment: Good point, removed. I'm surprised there's no 'standard' method to do this rather than having to use Linq, etc.

Comment: You could use foreach and not use .Text

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Good to know, i'll edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `System.Linq` because `Cast` should work.
I accomplished your desired result by using this code:

```
if ( listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Contains( comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show( "duplicate" );
}
else
{
    listBox1.Items.Add( comboBox1.SelectedItem );
}
```

**Custom controls (OP's situation):**
If the `foreach` solution works for your custom control and `.Text` isn't a valid extension method just use:

```
item.ToString().Contains(Combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the foreach loop without `Text`, as suggested by EpicKip

```
            if ( ListBox1.Items.Contains( ComboBox1.SelectedItem ) )
            {
                debugMsg( "duplicate", "" );
            }
            else
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add( ComboBox1.SelectedItem );
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ListBox.Items.Contains(TextBox.Text))
MessageBox.Show("Entry allready exists");
else
NameList.Items.Add(TextBox.Text.Trim());
```

I did this and it worked just fine.