# What should I add to a custom class so it works with System.Windows.Forms.Listbox.Items.Contains()..?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

What should I add to a custom class so it works with `System.Windows.Forms.Listbox.Items.Contains()`..?

I've created a class called "FileItem" for handling filenames in ListBoxes. It works as expected, but if I try to use `ListBox.Items.Contains()` to prevent duplicate items from being added, nothing happens. The `Contains()` function never returns True.

Here's the code. Add it to a VB.Net form named `frmTest` with a `ListBox1`, `Button1`, and `Button2`. Run it and press `Button1` multiple times. The duplicate warning message is never displayed.

```
Public Class frmTest

    Private Sub frmTest_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        With ListBox1
            .DisplayMember = "ShortName"
            .ValueMember = "LongName"
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As FileItem = New FileItem("C:\Windows\Notepad.exe")
        If ListBox1.Items.Contains(f) Then
            MsgBox("The file is already added and will be skipped.")
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(f)
        End If
        f = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim msg As String = ""
        For Each item As FileItem In ListBox1.Items
            msg &= item.FullName & vbCr
        Next
        MsgBox(msg)
    End Sub

    Private Class FileItem

        Private ReadOnly _FullName As String
        Private ReadOnly _ShortName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal FullName As String)
            _FullName = FullName
            If FullName.Contains("\") Then
                Dim pos As Integer = FullName.LastIndexOf("\")
                _ShortName = FullName.Substring(pos + 1)
            End If
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property FullName() As String
            Get
                Return _FullName
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property ShortName() As String
            Get
                Return _ShortName
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return _FullName
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: This is for a C# question, but it should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099868/listbox-items-contains-is-not-working

Comment: In C# you would implement Equals and GetHashCode using your data to create the uniqueness.  For GetHashCode  eg.  `return fileInfoInstance._FullName.GetHashCode(); `

Comment: You might consider making it a `Structure` instead of a `Class`, since you want different instances with the same contents to be treated as identical.  Everything is already read-only, so you wouldn't have to worry about the weirdness that can ensue with mutable structures.  I believe the default behavior of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for a structure would do what you want.

Comment: @Kevin and @hijinx thank you, your comments got me where I needed to go. I implemented `.Equals` and that gave my FileItem class what it needed. However, I'm still trying to understand what to do with GetHashCode(). That's a little bit deep for me.

Comment: @Craig thank you. I come from a long history of VBA, and I had custom types in my code, but I had yet to figure out their VB.Net equivalent is `Structure`. Per your suggestion, I'll try converting to that, but I'm not sure if it'll work. I had plans for my `FileItem` to part of a `FileItems` collection class - something like their equivalents in VBA when the Microsoft Scripting libraray (scrrun.dll) is used.

Comment: `Structure` and `Class` are very similar, in that they both define custom types with data and potentially associated code.  The difference is that `Structure` represents a "value" type where identity is based on the contents, where as `Class` represents a "reference" type where identity is based on the instance.  I don't think there is really an equivalent to `Structure` in VBA, though perhaps the VBA struct/record (forget the exact keyword for it) comes close.

Comment: Re what to do with `GetHashCode`, the contract for it is that things that compare equal must have the same hash code.  Basically, that's all.  Anything else is quality of implementation---it's desirable to not have many different things that end up with the same hash code because that will degrade the efficiency of the hashed containers `HashSet` and `Dictionary` (and some Linq things that use them behind the scenes).  It's usually a good idea for a custom implementation to be a composite of the hash codes of the representative data items.

Comment: In your case, identity is based on `FullName` so it would be fine for the hash code to just forward to the hash code of `FullName`.